# Hibernate @JoinTable not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, join, many-to-one

I'm having this weird problem going on with my application when it comes to **@JoinTable** use.

I have 3 entities: **EntityA**, **EntityB** and **EntityC**.

**EntityA.class**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entityA")
public Set<EntityB> getEntityBSet() {
    return entityBSet;
}
```

**EntityB.class**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENTITY_A", nullable = false)
public EntityA getEntityA() {
    return entityA;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "B_AND_C", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENTITY_B") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENTITY_C") })
public EntityC getEntityC() {
    return entityC;
}
```

**EntityC.class**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="entityC")
public Set<EntityB> getEntityBSet() {
    return entityBSet;
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to access entityB through entityA.getEntityBSet().

Hibernate doesnt generate the proper SQL for the relationship **entityB.entityC**, creating a Cartesian product:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ENTITY_B, B_C, ENTITY_C
WHERE B_C.ID_ENTITY_C = ENTITY_C.ID_ENTITY_C (+)
AND ENTITY_B.ID_ENTITY_A = ?
```

There should be the join between ENTITY_B and B_C:

```
AND ENTITY_B.ID_ENTITY_B = B_C.ID_ENTITY_B
```

On the other hand, when loading entityB through session.get(), the generated SQL is correct for that relationship (entityB.entityC).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to `.getEntityBSet()` after you close the hibernate session?

Comment: Hello @jmw5598! No, the session is open, the issue here is not `LazyInitializationException`. The thing is I'm having a performance issue because of this incorrect SQL (cartesian product of `ENTITY_C x B_C`), the entity is loaded according, but that SQL is a bottleneck.

Comment: @AnyOne ?? @AnyIdeas??